# I am getting this message when creating a new project

Tags: cache

Cannot create cache directory /home/cmnd/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an error, but a Composer warning, saying that it can't create its cache folder at `/home/cmnd/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/` (probably because of a permissions issue.

You can ignore it, but Composer will just run slower.